# Adding project from VS2013 to AzureDevOps

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, repository

Im using VS 2013 (CE).
Windows Server 2012 with a local install of Azure DevOps.

I can connect to the repository via the URL

http://example.local/DefaultCollection

Under defaultCollection i have another few test projects i.e.

/DefaultCollection/A-Project,

/DefaultCollection/B-Project.

For this example i will user C-Project which im trying to add to source control.

All im trying to do is add a project to this source control but i am experiencing issues that i would have thought shouldnt exist:

1. In VS2013, I add a new solution. I right click the project and select "Add solution to source control". Immediately it selects the project A-Project with the path /DefaultCollection/A-Project/C-Project. I dont want this as it resides inside another project.
2. From the web portal i create a new project and select Team Foundation Server (not Git as the examples online i have seen all select Git). In VS i create a brand new project and then attempt the same as 1 above but it tells me that i already have a project with this name under source control. I expand A-Project and i see it listed and undo any changes but it still doesnt add as i get some form of error.

Other problems range from the local version not mapped to, existing file exists/under source control to other errors.

What is the correct process to add a project to Azure Devops when using Visual Studio 2013 CE?

Comment: Hi @Computer, I noticed that `@ShamraiAleksander` has shared an good answer. Please have a try with it. If the answer is helpful to you, I recommend that you can mark it as the solution of this topic. This may also be verify helpful to more people who are looking for a solution for the similar questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default steps are described here: [Set up Team Foundation Version Control on your dev machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/set-up-team-foundation-version-control-your-dev-machine?view=azure-devops).

You have to:

1. Create a workspace from the target project.
2. Copy your project into the locally mapped folder.
3. Add your project to the source control.

As workaround:

1. Create workspace from the target project: [Create and work with workspaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/create-work-workspaces?view=azure-devops)
2. Copy your project into the locally mapped folder.
3. Add your project to the source control by: [Manually add files to version control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/add-files-server?view=azure-devops#manually-add-files-to-version-control)
4. Open the project and fix source control bindings:

[image]

Useful document: [Add files to the server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/add-files-server?view=azure-devops)